# Alljoyn sample code compile error on iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, alljoyn

I download the AllJoyn sample code and follow this link
[(Build)](https://allseenalliance.org/developers/develop/building/ios-osx)
to build it step by step.

- 1. I could build these samples successfully under the path(alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/)
- 2. I have no idea why I get the error as below when I build the notification service samples under the path (alljoyn-ios/services/alljoyn-notification-14.06.00-rel/objc/samples/)

     - I am sure I have correct header search paths and lib search paths. so is there any other items I should to check ?

  [image: List item]

---

update:

I edit the env path ALLSEEN_BASE_SERVICES_ROOT, and try to set my header & lib search path as below.

[image]

[image]

Now, I got this error in couple places. It's really creepy about the search path setting. I couldn't figure out what is the right settings in the service sample project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
cd alljoyn-ios
launchctl setenv ALLJOYN_SDK_ROOT `pwd`
cd services
launchctl setenv ALLSEEN_BASE_SERVICES_ROOT `pwd`
```

and then open Xcode from the command line so that it can pick up those variables ?

Also in the library search paths and header search paths I would replace the $(ALLJOYN_ROOT) with absolute paths to the files

It seems that it cannot find the ALLJOYN_ROOT that thus it complains about the symbols

If the above does not work try setting ALLJOYN_ROOT on command line and then opening Xcode from command line and compiling the whole thing with the steps mentioned

Comment: I edit setenv ALLSEEN_BASE_SERVICES_ROOT, and give all absolute to these files. It's still complier error. could you provide your search path setting for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong, change the "notification" to "alljoyn-notification-14.06.00-rel".
Just make sure your path is right and you will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add new folder "alljoyn" into "core" folder of "alljoyn-ios". ! 
This error will be no more !

Hierarchy -> 
       alljoyn-ios -> core -> alljoyn
Thanks,
RD